# angularjs: the variable being watched keeps reverting back to old value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a custom directive that opens the section based off of a variable on the main controller. If you click on the header (title) of a certain section it would open it and close the rest. But when I have a button inside one section that updates the variable it would revert back to the old value.

```
app.directive('sliders', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {},
            controller: function ($scope) {
                $scope.sliders = [];
                this.addSlider = function (section, element) {
                    $scope.sliders.push(section);
                };
                this.select = function (section) {
                    console.log(' select ' + $scope.$parent.stepToShow);
                    $scope.$parent.stepToShow = section.step;
                };
            },
            template: '<div class="sliders" ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    })
    .directive('sliderSection', function () {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            require: '^sliders',
            transclude: true,
            scope: {
                title: '@',
                step: '@'
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, slidersCtrl) {
                scope.selected = function () {
                    return scope.step == scope.$parent.$parent.stepToShow;
                };
                scope.select = function () {
                    console.log('select() ' + scope.step);
                    slidersCtrl.select(scope);
                };
                slidersCtrl.addSlider(scope);
                scope.$watch(function () { return scope.$parent.$parent.stepToShow; }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    console.log(' watch ' + scope.$parent.$parent.stepToShow);
                    if (newVal == scope.step) {
                        element.find('.slider-body').slideDown();
                    }
                    else {
                        element.find('.slider-body').slideUp();
                    }
                });
            },
            template: '<div id="" class="slider-section" step="{{step}}" ng-click="select()">' +
                            '<div class="slider-header" >{{title}}</div>' +
                            '<div class="slider-body"  ng-transclude></div>' +     
                        '<div>'
        };
    });
```

It's better if I show you through plunkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/aFMkWYmINb26M8cJFzgl?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a click handler on the button but you also have a click handler on it's parents as well. Both events will fire when you click the button so they are canceling each other

You need to prevent the button click from propagation or you need to check the event target on the parent click.

To stop propagation pass in `$event` to the `ng-click` handler.

```
<button ng-click="setStepToShow('1', $event)">Next Step</button>
```

Then in handler code:

```
   $scope.setStepToShow = function (step, $event) {
      $event.stopPropagation()
       /* other code as original */
    }
```

Instead of using `if...$$phase` then `$apply()` just use `$timeout()`

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cAFboXVovyOwM2L6PrWS?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: ah, nice! thanks! i didn't know about that propagation. what does propagation do? it just picks one? Also, how long of a timeout should i use for these? 1000? I've been trying to find the sweet spot for timeout but really couldn't find the most efficient.

Comment: don't need any time set, it just puts the operation at end of stack if a digest is in progress. Events bubble (propagate) up the document. Read up on event bubbling